# SSIS ForEach From Variable Enumerator, list created with C# - The object in the variable does not contain an enumerator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I've been chipping away at refactoring an SSIS package that copies a pile of log files into a folder on our network, examines all of the files in the destination folder and then deletes any that have aged past our retention policy. It seems like it should all work but for the error above.

Outline:
Variable "dailyFilesToDelete" of type Object, populated by a script task inside a ForEach File Loop. 
I simplified my code to add a single file that I created to test this new package with and try to get to the heart of the issue.

```
var fileListDelete = new List<string>();
fileListDelete.Add(@"Q:\xpcttvcpc_live_Full_201912050000.bak");
Dts.Variables["dailyFilesToDelete"].Value = fileListDelete.GetEnumerator();
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

The next step is the Foreach Loop that is failing.

Enumerator: Foreach From Variable Enumerator

Enumerator variable: User::dailyFilesToDelete

Variable mapping: User::deleteFileName

I suspect that the issue is with how I'm passing my list of strings into dailyFilesToDelete. I initially was passing in the List itself, and once I saw the "variable does not contain an enumerator" error I was sure that adding the GetEnumerator call would fix it.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're creating your enumerator correctly, but I only say that because I'm looking at C# examples online and they are quite different from what you're doing here. I am not a C# developer, but I found the following example pretty informative on how to create an enumerator in C#: https://dotnetcodr.com/2017/11/15/implementing-an-enumerator-for-a-custom-object-in-net-c-3/

Comment: Thanks, but that example has more to do with creating an enumerator for a custom object. I could create a class with a single string property and generate an enumerator out of it, but that seems like a bit of overkill. I'm pretty sure I've used this method in a C# app before with no problems. I'm sure that there's something much simpler that's wrong. Unfortunately setting a breakpoint inside any script task has stopped working for some reason, when I'm debugging now visual studio just blows right past those and only breaks on the pre/post execute points I set on tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is assigning the enumerator result to the variable. Try it just as

```
Dts.Variables["dailyFilesToDelete"].Value = fileListDelete;
```

Behind the scenes, the SSIS Foreach Enumerator will call the Enumerator method to make the magic happen.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I knew it had to be something about how SSIS was managing the variables.